# Set Different Umask For Files And Folders

Tags: bash, permissions, umask

I am writing a bash script to update some files/directories and I want to run umask in the script to set default permissions for files/directories created by the script. I know I can umask to set the permissions for both files and directories however I need the permissions to be different for files and folders.

```
I want files to be:   -rw----r-- (0604)
I want folders to be: drwx-----x (0701)
```

Can I do this using umask? If so how do I go about doing it? If not what is the best way to achieve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure you want --x on directories (others)? it means others can read files in directory only if they know the filename. if you can accept rwx---r-x on directories, umask 072 will just fit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting requirement. Currently (at least in `bash`), `umask` is a global setting and you cannot set it based on object type.

One solution that comes to mind would be to set the `umask` to the file variant and then intercept calls to `mkdir` (such as with a user-created `mkdir` script earlier in the path) to do:

```
umask 0701 ; /path/to/real/mkdir $1 ; umask 0604
```

That way, assuming all your directory creations are done with `mkdir`, you can ensure they use a different `umask` setting.

Note that the script should probably be a little more robust such as restoring the previous `umask` rather than forcing it to `0604`, and adding some better error checking and possibly the ability to handle multiple arguments.

But that's all detail, the framework above should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 5):

The `umask` is an attribute of the process not of a file - that is part of UNIX architecture and is nothing todo with Bash, or any other shell program.

The real issue is that the programs you are using do not allow the permissions to be changed on creation.  In C, for example, `mkdir` has a second parameter, the *mode*.

You don't need to write C though, Python and Perl allow you to use the low-level interfaces.  The permissions will be modified by the process's `umask` so, if you don't want any modification, set `unmask` to zero.

```
/home/user1> umask 000
/home/user1> python -c 'import os;os.mkdir("mydir",0701)'
/home/user1> ls -ld mydir
drwx-----x 2 user1 QAPLADV 4096 Sep 16 10:28 mydir

/home/user1> python -c 'import os;os.open("myfile",os.O_CREAT,0604)'
/home/user1> ls -l myfile
-rw----r-- 1 user1 QAPLADV 0 Sep 16 10:32 myfile
```

Don't forget that `umask` is still 000 at this point, you might want to set it back to its previous value if you are doing any other work in the same process.

Here is a Perl version if you prefer:

```
perl -e "mkdir mydir,0701"
perl -MFcntl -e 'sysopen(my $h,"myfile",O_EXCL|O_CREAT,0604)'
```

Of course if you have a large number of files, and you are likely to be running this often, then you would be much better off writing a Perl or Python program to do the job - calling perl or python for each file is a tad inefficient.

Comment: you must know that the unix util mkdir a accepts apermission argument, i.e `mkdir -m 750 umaskTest` works exactly the same, but without all the extra `-c ....` stuff? A good first 2 paragraphs. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter that should have been an|the answer

Comment: Just to clarify, `umask` is indeed a property of the process but to say it has nothing to do with shells is incorrect (or misleading). Bash, for one, maintains its own internal copy of what the umask *should* be and uses that when creating files, directories, and so forth. It's *this* internal copy that's modified by the `umask` builtin that `bash` has. See `bash-5.0`, `builtins/umask.def` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Put following in the user's .bashrc:

umask 0222

alias mkdir='mkdir -m u=rx,g=rx,o='

The file will be created with umask 0222, whereas mkdir will use umask 0227.